# Ring to infinite plate capacitance calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I don't know how to calculate the capacitance between a conductive ring and a conductive infinite plate.
The ring has internal radius **R1** and external radius **R2** and is placed on a parallel plane with distance **D** from the infinite plate.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me in this matter.

[image: top view]
[image: side view]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) What have you attempted to solve this so far?

Comment: Thank you Sanya. I don't know how to define the Gaussian Surface.

Comment: sorry for not being more specific - what I'd like you to do is to edit your question and sketch your idea at solution and the point at which you are stuck :)

Comment: I'm stuck just at the beginning! :(      I can not define the Gaussian surface. Visible symmetry in the problem is not enough for me to down sample it to a known situation.

Comment: I was wondering if I replace the infinite plate with a ring plate similar to the ring plate that i have, the calculated capacitance would be good approximation.

Comment: Is it the case that $D>>(R_2-R_1)$ ?

Comment: Dear Dillon dimensions are as follows: **R1** = 25mm, **R2** = 34.5mm,  7< **D** <34
In other words, for the ring : ID = 50 and OD = 69

Comment: There is a problem in the capacitor you have conceived. One conductor, the sheet is of infinite size, and the other conductor, the ring, has finite size. A capacitor must have equal charge on both conductors. If suppose a finite charge exists on the ring, then the charge density on the sheet will be essentially zero here, since a finite charge is spread out over an infinite sheet. Do you get my point?

Comment: I think that the method of images would be helpful. The metal plate can be replaced by a similar ring at a distance D below the plate and of the opposite charge on the 1st ring..

Comment: Related to [Force of Electrostatic Attraction between 2 rings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253387)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is far from simple. There is no obvious Gaussian Surface which will make this problem easy, because the electric field does not follow a simple pattern as it does in the case of parallel plane or coaxial cylindrical or concentric spherical conducting plates. The ring (actually an annulus) is conducting and has a finite width, so the distribution of charge will not generally be uniform, though it will have circular symmetry. You could get a numerical answer by solving Laplace's Equation with boundary conditions, but you seem to be asking for an algebraic formula.

A simpler scenario is to assume that the annulus is infinitesimally thin - ie $R_1\approx R_2$. The obvious solution uses the [Method of Image Charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges). The ring induces a mirror image with opposite charge in the plate; the scenario is equivalent to 2 rings carrying charges $-Q, +Q$ a distance $2D$ apart. The solution is still far from easy.

The steps involved are :

1. Calculate the [electric field at any off-axis point due to a charged ring](http://student.ndhu.edu.tw/~d9914102/Teaching/EM/Paper/data/Off-axis%20electric%20field%20of%20a%20ring%20of%20charge_Project%20Paper.pdf).
2. Hence find the [force between two identical coaxial charged rings](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267465172_Electric_force_between_two_charged_coaxial_rings).
3. Calculate the work done to move a ring of charge $+\delta q$ from ring 2 carrying charge $-q$ to ring 1 carrying charge $+q$, which are distance $2D$ apart.
4. Integrate again, from $0$ to $Q$, to find the total work done $U$ to create the charged rings $-Q,+Q$.
5. Use $U=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$ to find capacitance.

Comment: Naïvely, shouldn't the capacitance vanish in the limit that the rings have zero thickness?  As we approach zero thickness, the fields near the rings approach those of a line charge.  This means that the potential will diverge as $R_1 \to R_2$, meaning that the potential difference between the rings (or between the ring and the plate) will diverge.  Since we have a finite amount of charge and $Q/V = C$, the capacitance must vanish in the limit of infinitesimally thin rings.